# Start with observable of an array and then push items on it from an item observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm weirdly stuck with the following:

- I have an Observable that emits either an array with some items or an empty array, and this Observable emits only once - let's call it `startingArray$`
- Then I have a hot Observable that emits individual items that I would like to push to `startingArray` once `startingArray` has been emitted - let's call it `additions$`
- What code gives me the resulting observable `startingArrayPlusAdditions$` that continuosly grows as more items are emitted?
- `startingArrayPlusAdditions$` should emit every time `additions$` emits, but it should not emit when `startingArray$` emits initially

Comment: I don't understand when `startingArray$` should be emitted...

Comment: @martin `startingArray$` is also a hot Observable, so it decides itself when it will emit. All that is known is that it will emit only once and it will be either an empty array or an array with some items in it. Once `startingArray$` has emitted only then should `additions$` be collected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that I understood all your problem but here's a proposal:

```
const { Observable }  = Rx;

const startingArray$ = Observable.of([1, 2, 3]);

const additions$ = Observable.from([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);

const startingArrayPlusAdditions$ = startingArray$
  .combineLatest(additions$)
  .scan((acc, current) => {
    const [startingArray, addition] = current;

    if (acc === null) {
      return [...startingArray, addition];
    } else {
      acc.push(addition);
      return acc;
    }
  }, null)
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

So just as you asked:

> startingArrayPlusAdditions$ should emit every time additions$ emits, but it should not emit when startingArray$ emits initially

Here's a working Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rKXLJrmA7mSzpQgoemlD?p=preview